# Python or C: Turning a List of Pairs into a Connected List

Tags: algorithm

What is an efficient algorithm in C or python that, given a list of unordered pairs signifying a relationship between two numbers, will combine the pairs so that they form a continuous list.

For example, given the following:

```
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(3, 2)
(4, 3)
```

produce the following: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Obviously, this would not work where there are gaps or loops in the pairs, e.g., `(0, 1) (3, 4)`, and in those cases, throw an error message or something similar.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Basically you want to merge arrays and remove duplicates?

Comment: No, the order of the list is based on the original pairs.

Comment: @speedplane: Really?  So what would the result be for `(1,2), (0,1), (2,3)`?

Comment: `(1,2), (0,1), (2,3)` --> `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Saying "what have you tried" to this question is pretty rude since the one saying it can't solve it themselves (if you can, please step up and grab your millions of dollars in price money for solving the P vs NP problem).

Comment: Must all pairs be included or is it enough that all numbers are included? I'm trying to get to the bottom with your definition of a "loop in the pairs". Is `[(0,1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]` valid with the solution `[0, 1, 2]`?

Comment: @Emil: AFAIK, NP-complete != impossible. That said, I'm not sure there's enough info here to be sure that a ham cycle is what's needed. Isn't a simple topological sort sufficient?

Comment: Oli, NP-complete means that, as far as we know, it is not possible to solve in polynomial time. The question asks about an *efficient* algorithm.

Comment: @EmilVikström: It's true, it does ask for that.  But as I was saying, it's not clear we need something as complex as a Hamiltonian path here.

Comment: Oli, I agree with you! Let's see what the answer to my question is. I do not think topological sorting applies because this is an undirected graph (see the example provided in the original question).

Comment: Yes, your example would contain a loop and would be invalid input. Not sure how this question turned so heated.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers can be modeled as a vertex in a graph. Each element in the list will then represent an edge between the nodes.

What you are looking for is then the 'Eulerian Path' of this graph. There are multiple algorithms for this. Check out the well known algorithms at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not an Eulerian path (visiting each edge once) but a [Hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) (visiting each vertex once), because you do not want to have loops in your path which by the definition of a loop means you don't want to visit any vertex two times.

This problem is known to be [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete_problem) which means that there is no known efficient algorithms (if by "efficient" you mean in [polynomial time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Polynomial_time)).

If you can find an efficient algorithm for this problem, you would also solve the [P vs NP problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) by showing that P and NP are equal. Most computer scientists believe that the answer to the P vs NP problem is "No, efficient algorithms for NP problems are impossible", which means that there is no possibility of an efficient algorithm to your question (although it remains to be proved).